# How to find the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!(n^4+n^2+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find this sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n!(n^4+n^2+1)}$$

My try: since
$$n^4+n^2+1=(n^2+1)^2-n^2=(n^2+n+1)(n^2-n+1)$$
then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n!(n^4+n^2+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2n\cdot n!}\left(\dfrac{1}{n(n-1)+1}-\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)+1}\right)$$
then I can't go further.

Comment: The tag ([tag:summation]) is supposed to be about finite sums (see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/summation/info).) The tag ([tag:sequences-and-series]) is for infinite series.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Let $S$ denote the sum to be evaluated. For every $n$,
$$
\frac2{n^4+n^2+1}=\frac{n+1}{n(n+1)+1}-\frac{n-1}{(n-1)n+1},
$$
hence
$$
2S=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{n+1}{n(n+1)+1}\frac1{n!}-\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{k-1}{(k-1)k+1}\frac1{k!}.
$$
The RHS is almost a telescoping series. To wit, the change of variable $n=k-1$ in the last sum and the fact that its $k=1$ term is zero yield
$$
2S=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{n+1}{n(n+1)+1}\frac1{n!}-\frac{n}{n(n+1)+1}\frac1{(n+1)!},
$$
that is,
$$
2S=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{(n+1)^2-n}{n(n+1)+1}\frac1{(n+1)!}\stackrel{k=n+1}{=}\sum_{k\geqslant2}\frac1{k!}=\mathrm e-\frac1{0!}-\frac1{1!},
$$
and finally,
$$
S=\frac12\mathrm e-1.
$$

Comment: And [WA knows it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+1%2F%28n!*%28n^4%2Bn^2%2B1%29%29+from+n%3D1+to+n%3Dinfinity)...

Comment: It's nice ! Thank you +1

Comment: brother why is your answer different from this one https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2029192/501526

Comment: @MohanSharma You are probably enquiring about the "results", not the answers themselves. The discrepancy of the results might be due to the fact that the series here starts at $n=1$ while the series there starts at $n=0$, don't you think?