# Solution of this summation: $\sum_{i=1}^{10} {\frac{i}{i^4+i^2+1}}$

Tags: summation

The summation in question:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{10} {\frac{i}{i^4+i^2+1}}$$

I have been able to factorize $i^4+i^2+1$ as $(i^2+i+1)(i^2-i+1)$ but I doubt this will help.

What is the solution?

Comment: are you meant to come up with a formula? or why can you not simply add up the 10 terms?

Comment: @Chinny84 I need a proper solution using rules of summation. Using brute force isn't allowed

Comment: You might like the discussion on this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029003/a-nice-infinite-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1nn4n21-frac re: ${\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty}\frac{1}{n!(n^4+n^2+1)}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writting $$\sum^{10}_{i=1}\frac{i}{i^4+i^2+1} = \frac{1}{2}\sum^{10}_{i=1}\bigg[\frac{(i^2+i+1)-(i^2-i+1)}{(i^2+i+1)(i^2-i+1)}\bigg]$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}\sum^{10}_{i=1}\bigg[\frac{1}{i^2-i+1}-\frac{1}{i^2+i+1}\bigg]$$

Now Using Telescopic Sum (expanding summation), Then we get

$$ =\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{1}{1^2-1+1}-\frac{1}{10^2+10+1}\bigg]= \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{111}\right) = \frac{55}{111}$$

Comment: It might help the OP if you were more explicit about why all the middle terms cancel out.

Comment: @juantheron I don't think that the middle terms can be cancelled out this way...

Comment: I meant write $\frac{1}{i^2-i+1}-\frac{1}{i^2+i+1}$ as $\frac{1}{i(i-1)+1}-\frac{1}{(i+1)i+1}$ so it is clearly in the form of $f(i)-f(i+1)$.

Comment: So that factorisation did come into play?! Haha thanks!

Comment: It should be $\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{111})$